# How to make sqlite3.connect() fail if the db file does not exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

`sqlite3.connect()` will create the db file if it does not exist. I'd like it to fail. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: you can use `os.path.exists()` to check the file first

Comment: I could. But I'd expect an option to make it easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first way is to check the file path with `os.path.isfile` :

```
import sqlite3
import os

my_path = 'database.db' # or 'absolute_path/to/the/file'
if os.path.isfile(my_path):
    sqlite3.connect(my_path)
```

---

Otherwise you can use the `uri=True` parameter to specify an opening `mode` and raise an error in case the file is missing. 
Without the `mode`, the file will be created if not exists, so you can use for example `rw` or `ro` to avoid the new file :

- to open with read & write mode :

  ```
  sqlite3.connect('file:database.db?mode=rw', uri=True)
  ```
- to open in read only mode :

  ```
  sqlite3.connect('file:database.db?mode=ro', uri=True)
  ```

This will raise the following error if the file doesn't exists :

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

You can find more about these modes in these chapters of the doc :

https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#urifilenamesinsqlite3open

---

To be able to open files with special characters (special for an URI), another way is to use the following method :

```
import pathlib

my_db = pathlib.Path('path/to/data?ba=se.db').as_uri()
sqlite3.connect('{}?mode=rw'.format(my_db), uri=True)

# or sqlite3.connect(f'{my_db}?mode=rw', uri=True)  with f-string
```

Comment: This is a little combersome. If the database file name contains `?` and `=`, it should be escaped first? In this sense, maybe checking `os.path.exists()` is better?

Comment: adding `?` or `=` in a filename proves a real passion of risks :) Eventually this can be handled with the feature added in python 3.7 https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect : *Changed in version 3.7: database can now also be a path-like object, not only a string.*

Comment: It is not that I want to use `?` and `=` in filenames. But I need to code to guard against such cases if I use the `uri` option. Not sure path-like object  solves the problem. If it is used, I don't see a way to specify read-only.

Comment: indeed, i was thinking that creating a path-like object could fail if the path doesn't exist, but i can't find a way either. Not sure you can find other solutions than `os.path.exists()` or uri

Comment: @user1424739  At least the answer provides a solution to your question.  You can always perform prior file/path validation to exclude files that would contain `?` and `=`.  This would require a very simple regex check that excludes certain character and/or suffixes on the filename.  Being security minded is good, but I still wonder if this level of concern is necessary since if some rogue process had crafted and created a filename that could spoof the URI format, then it's likely that that process has already compromised the system beyond tricking your app into opening a newly-created db file.

Comment: This is a one-and-done solution. dbfile = f"file:{DATABASE}?mode=rw" and then add uri=True to the connect. Certainly testing if the file exists works, but seriously, SQLite doesn't have it's own way to do this? Yes it does, and this is the solution. The behavior of SQLite is another issue. Creating the database should be an explicit action, not the default.