# Connecting to sqlite3 database from Flask application and printing data on a webpage

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm using sqlite3 database, conda environment and python Flask to create a simple web app that displays the users from a db table.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db", check_same_thread=False)
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
    db.commit()
    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
            {% for row in rows %}
                <li>{{row["name"]}}, {{row["email"]}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

There's no error but when running the app on localhost no list is displayed on the page. There's only the heading and the bullet point. So I guess db.execute is returning an empty object.

Can anyone please tell me what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: sqlite3 will create a database if it doesn't find one so my guess is that your path "data.db" is not what you expect.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828286/how-to-make-sqlite3-connect-fail-if-the-db-file-does-not-exist.

Comment: @AllanWind I have manually created the table and inserted 2 rows. Moreover, I checked sqlite3 version from inside python (print(sqlite3.version)) it is 2.6.0 while the sqlite3 terminal shows the version 3.33.0. 
Is this the cause?

Comment: sqlite3.version is 'The version number of this [python] module'.  If you want to compare the database version you have to use `sqlite3.sqlite_version`

Comment: The issue is the variable `row` which is a `tuple` and not `namedtuple`, you need to access the `row["name"]` as `row[0]` based on the index in the tuple.

Comment: See row_factory in https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thanks, I would recommend to use Flask-SQLAlchemy for your DB operations. It's way easier & versatile. (https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open cursor before fetch result

```
def index():
    db = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows)
```

p.s. rows is not dictionary it is `tuple`, use `zip` to convert to `dict`:
if you have just two colums in users
`rows=[dict(zip(('name', 'email'), row)) for row in rows]`