# SQLAlchemy and SQLite3: Error if database file does not exist

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I would like SQLAlchemy to return an error if the underlying SQLite3 database file does not exist.

I've looked around, and tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeTable(Base):
    id = Column(Integer)

DB_SPECIFIER = 'sqlite+pysqlite:////tmp/non-exist.db?mode=rw'
engine = create_engine(DB_SPECIFIER, echo=False, future=True, connect_args={'uri': True})
session = Session(engine)
x = session.query(SomeTable)
```

I'd like the create_engine call to fail if /tmp/non-exist.db does not exist.  I thought using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828286/how-to-make-sqlite3-connect-fail-if-the-db-file-does-not-exist) would work, but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's in the docs, though fairly hidden:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#uri-connections

So you'd do:

```py
DB_SPECIFIER = 'sqlite:///file:/tmp/non-exist.db?mode=ro&uri=true'
engine = create_engine(DB_SPECIFIER, echo=False, future=True)
```

It picks this apart and sends arguments to the connection, the rest through to the URI. (You can also add some lock disabling and such there, if that helps, since it's read only).

Comment: Read only prevents from updating the SQLite file